# Curious about effect of recursion of a method

Tags: python, recursion

I have written an instance method which uses recursion to find a certain solution. It works perfectly fine except the time when I'm exiting the if-elif block. I call the function itself inside IF block. Also, I have only one return statement. The output from the method is weird for me to understand. Here is the code and the output:

```
def create_schedule(self):
    """
    Creates the day scedule for the crew based on the crew_dict passed.
    """   
    sched_output = ScheduleOutput()
    assigned_assignements = []
    for i in self.crew_list:
        assigned_assignements.extend(i.list_of_patients)

    rest_of_items = []
    for item in self.job.list_of_patients:
        if item not in assigned_assignements:
            rest_of_items.append(item)

    print("Rest of the items are:", len(rest_of_items))

    if len(rest_of_items) != 0:
        assignment = sorted(rest_of_items, key=lambda x: x.window_open)[0]
        # print("\nNext assignment to be taken ", assignment)
        output = self.next_task_eligibility(assignment, self.crew_list)
        if len(output) != 0:
            output_sorted = sorted(output, key=itemgetter(2))
            crew_to_assign = output_sorted[0][1]
            assignment.eta = output_sorted[0][4]
            assignment.etd = int(assignment.eta) + int(assignment.care_duration)
            crew = next((x for x in self.crew_list if x.crew_number == crew_to_assign), None)
            self.crew_list.remove(crew)
            crew.list_of_patients.append(assignment)
            crew.time_spent = assignment.etd
            self.crew_list.append(crew)

            self.create_schedule()
        else:
            print("*" * 80, "\n", "*" * 80, "\nWe were not able to assign a task so stopped.\n", "*" * 80, "\n", "*" * 80)

            sched_output.crew_output = self.crew_list
            sched_output.patients_left = len(rest_of_items)

    elif not rest_of_items:
        print("Fully solved.")
        sched_output.crew_output = self.crew_list
        sched_output.patients_left = 0

    print("After completely solving coming here.")
    return sched_output
```

This was the output:

```
Rest of the items are: 10
Rest of the items are: 9
Rest of the items are: 8
Rest of the items are: 7
Rest of the items are: 6
Rest of the items are: 5
Rest of the items are: 4
Rest of the items are: 3
Rest of the items are: 2
Rest of the items are: 1
Rest of the items are: 0
Fully solved.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
After completely solving coming here.
```

What I don't understand is that as soon as my list rest_of_items is empty, I assign data to sched_output and return it. However, print statement is being executed for the same number of time as recursion was done. How can I avoid this?

My output is perfectly fine. All I want to do is understand the cause of this behaviour and how to avoid it.

Comment: As a side note, you've written an "instance method", or just a "method"; a "class method" is a special thing (usually decorated with `@classmethod`) which is meant to be called on the class itself, rather than on objects that are instances of that class.

Comment: @abarnert fixed. Apologies.

Comment: In the future, please try to provide a [mcve] -- the **shortest possible code**, with everything needed for someone else to run it themselves, that illustrates a given question.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Noted. I'll follow the guide. Thanks. :)

Comment: Run this through a debugger and it will be clear why you are seeing this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you call your `create_schedule` function within itself before the function finishes, once it has gotten to the end and doesn't need to call itself again, each function ends, and hits the "After completely solving coming here.", at the end of the function.

This means that each function, after calling itself, is still running - just stuck at the line where it calls itself - until they have all completed, which is when the paused functions can finish their task, printing out your statement.

Comment: Does that also mean each function also call `return sched_output`?

Comment: Yes, @RyanCyrus, but they do nothing with the returned value.

Comment: Is it a normal behaviour? Can it be improved?

Comment: To improve it, you could work upon what @abamert has done, and copy the function into another one with a different name, which is called by the original function, and have the print statement only happen in the original function, or have the print statement after where you call this method in the first place. This would also mean that none of them `return sched_output` if you only include it in the original. Refer to @abermert's answer to see this in action.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's printing out 11 times is that you always call `print` at the end of the function, and you're calling the function 11 times. (It's really the same reason you get `Rest of the items are: …` 11 times, which should be a lot more obvious.)

Often, the best solution is to redesign things so instead of doing "side effects" like `print` inside the function, you just return a value, and the caller can then do whatever side effects it wants with the result. In that case, it doesn't matter that you're calling `print` 11 times; the `print` will only happen once, in the caller.

---

If that isn't possible, you can change this so that you only `print` something when you're at the top of the stack. But in many recursive functions, there's no obvious way to figure that out without passing down more information:

```
def create_schedule(self, depth=0):
    # etc.
    self.create_schedule(depth+1)
    # etc.
    if not depth:
        print('After completely solving come here.')
    returns sched_output
```

---

The last resort is to just wrap the recursive function, like this:

```
def _create_schedule(self):
    # etc.
    self._create_schedule()
    # etc.
    # don't call print
    return sched_output

def create_schedule(self):
    result = self._create_schedule()
    print('After completely solving come here.')
    return result
```

That's usually only necessary when you need to do some one-time setup for the recursive process, but here you want to do some one-time post-processing instead, which is basically the same problem, so it can be solved the same way.

(Of course this is really just the first solution in disguise, but it's hidden inside the implementation of `create_schedule`, so you don't need to change the interface that the callers see.)

Comment: Cool, This makes sense. Thanks for explanation. I'll implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You have `print("After completely solving coming here.")` at the end of your recursive function. That line will be executed once for each recursion.

Consider this simple example, which recreates your issue:

```
def foo(x):
    print("x = {x}".format(x=x))
    if x > 1:
        foo(x-1)
    print("Done.")
```

Now call the function:

```
>>> foo(5)
x = 5
x = 4
x = 3
x = 2
x = 1
Done.
Done.
Done.
Done.
Done.
```

As you can see, on the final call to `foo(x=0)`, it will print `"Done."`. At that point, the function will return to the previous call, which will also print `"Done."` and so on.